# Extract structured data from many MS Word files

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have ~160 MS Word files that contain structured data.  The data is formatted identically across all files and resides in a tabular format.

I'd like to extract the data into a database, XML or just an aggregate table without opening each of the files independently.

Is there a tool or method I can use to extract this data?

Comment: If they are 2007 format (.docx) then try renaming them to .zip and extracting the contents. See if there's anything in there that will help you on your way...

Comment: @Jaymz they're 2003 format, but I could probably save them as 2007 format (with a fair bit of effort)

Comment: With ~160 files, loading them and re-saving them as 2007 would probably be just as much effort as manually doing whatever you're trying to do :P

Comment: @Jaymz yep. just tried saving one into 07 format and the XML is somewhat cryptic -- it's hard to find the tabular structure (and XML isn't foreign to me)

Comment: Hmm, thought it might be, hence my comment instead of answer :)
Sorry, no more help I can give...

Answer (score 1):

Well you could write a code using python (or any other language, but i prefer python :D) to extract the data from the files and put it into a database. You can use the Python UNO module to use the open office API and extract the data. Some example code in python that may help you out http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/PyUNO_samples. The overall code should be easy to write if the data is well structured.